# Número de 9 digitos se guarda incorrectamente a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema que se me presentó y no entiendo porqué sucede. Tengo en mi php una variable que es un número de un largo máximo de 9 números y al momento de subirlo a la BD aparece el número **2147483647**, cuando reviso la tabla, sé que es el número máximo de un int en sql.

¿Alguna idea de como sucedió o como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: No se puede adivinar el problema sin un [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

MySQL provee múltiples tipos de campos que podemos elegir según nuestras necesidades,  puedes encontrar la lista para enteros y sus limitaciones [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html):

Campos para enteros en MySQL:

```
Type      | Storage    | Minimum Value        | Maximum Value       |
----------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
TINYINT   | 1          | -128                 | 127                 |
----------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
SMALLINT  | 2          | -32768               | 32767               |
----------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
MEDIUMINT | 3          | -8388608             | 8388607             |
----------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
INT       | 4          | -2147483648          | 2147483647          |
----------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
BIGINT    | 8          | -9223372036854775808 | 9223372036854775807 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

En lugar de utilizar un campo `INT` cambialo a `BIGINT` si el numero es mayor al rango de `INT`.

Si el valor que estas insertando esta dentro de los rangos de `INT` asegurate de que en la cadena no haya algún caracter no númerico.

Comment: Acostumbro a los campo int cuando se que se requieren números mayores a 7 digitos no colocarle al int la longitud, es decir solo int. No se si es una buena practica.

Comment: @Scorpion Realmente colocar la longitud del `int(longitud)` no hará que el campo ocupe más o menos espacio. Lo mejor es adaptar el tipo de campo al tipo de dato. es decir si voy a utilizar un campo como boleano (0 ó 1) es mejor utilizar TINYINT que  INT con longitud 1, pues en memoria TINYINT ocupa 1/4 de lo que ocupa INT, aun que los 2 datos tengan la misma longitud.

Comment: El tipo de la columna en la BD no parece ser el problema aquí, porque en la BD encuentra el valor `2147483647` que supera los 9 dígitos.

Comment: @sstan `2147483647` ese es el valor máximo de un campo INT en MySQL en un INT no puedes guardar un numero mas grande que ese, puedes hacer la prueba si quieres. Por ejemplo `2147483647+1` no se puede almacenar en un INT. Nada tiene que ver los dígitos.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, pero lo que digo es que ese máximo ya son 10 dígitos. OP está teniendo problemas con un número que no supera los 9 dígitos, de modo que su problema no puede ser que se está pasando del límite del tipo de la columna que usa. El problema debe ser otro. A menos que conozcas algún número de 9 dígitos que no quepa en un `int`.

Comment: @sstan Cierto ni me habia fijado y me he cegado, mal lei la pregunta del OP. Entonces no queda otra la cadena que esta pasando contiene algun carecter no numérico. Edito la respuesta. gracias por la observación.

Comment: Eso no lo sé. Si existe un caracter no númerico en la cadena, ¿esto causaría que MySQL guardara `2147483647`? Yo pensaba que, o daría un error, o tal vez, guaradaría `0`.